# Moving quotchap further up the page

Tags: quotchap

Im currently writing my thesis which is limited by page number and am using quotchap to mark my chapters. I have managed to reduce the chapter number size using a bit of code from another answer, however I want to move the number further up the page as it currently takes up half of my page.
Is there any way to do this?

heres my current code;

```
\usepackage[grey,times]{quotchap}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\chapnumfont}{%
\usefont{T1}{\@defaultcnfont}{b}{n}\fontsize{100}{150}\selectfont% Default:100/130
    \color{chaptergrey}%
}
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 1):

You can move the chapter numbers further up the page by using:

```
\renewcommand{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\vspace*{-3\baselineskip}}
```

I put -3 there now, you can move it further up by making the number more negative.